# std::vector may terminate without throwing

Tags: c++

I wanted to test whether my program will be able to run in parallel by pre-allocating the memory I need.
I noticed that `std::vector` seems to call a terminate without raising an exception at the moment it should actually work.
I have no trouble if I instead use `new`. The program shows in both cases the same output.

```
// estimate maximum number of threads
auto test_alloc = [](int num_threads, const size_t num_voxels) {
    auto ta_impl = [](int num_threads, const size_t num_voxels, const auto& fcn) {
        if(num_threads < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        constexpr int safety_margin = 1;
        char *tmp = nullptr;
        try {
            const size_t n = (num_threads+safety_margin+1) * num_voxels;
            //tmp = new char[n];
            std::vector<uint8_t> tmp(n, 0);
        }
        catch(std::bad_alloc &ba) {
            //if(tmp) delete tmp;
            std::cerr << "Not enough memory for " << num_threads << " threads :(" << std::endl;
            return fcn(--num_threads, num_voxels, fcn);
        }
        //if(tmp) delete tmp;
        return num_threads;
    };
    return ta_impl(num_threads, num_voxels, ta_impl);
};
```

Output:

```
Not enough memory for 8 threads :(
Not enough memory for 7 threads :(
Not enough memory for 6 threads :(
Not enough memory for 5 threads :(
Not enough memory for 4 threads :(
Not enough memory for 3 threads :(
```

Comment: maybe it had enough memory for 2 threads?

Comment: It terminates at two

Comment: `volatile` and `std::vector` do not mix.  IIRC there are no volatile member function overloads.  Why are you using `volatile`?

Comment: `std::thread` can throw `std::system_error` on failure. Are you sure this isn't the cause of the crash? What's the complete error message you're getting on crash? If you're low on memory, it's possible it can't create enough space for any of the thread control block / stack space

Comment: How does it terminate?

Comment: The volatile I just added because I don't want the compiler to remove tmp if I enable optimizations.  
This test function is not in a thread or parallel region. I am not sure how it terminates. There is no output. It happens in std::vector

Comment: I suspect that your platform is one of those that don't actually allocate the memory until it's touched. If it is, you will encounter the same problem once you start writing to your `new`-allocated memory (for instance if you zero-initialise it with `new char[n]()`).

Comment: Seems to fail in __builtin_memset

Comment: I think you have misunderstood `volatile`.

Comment: @molbdnilo new char[n]() also fails. But why it does not throw if allocation fails. Additionally, there _is_ enough memory for two threads.

Comment: @dgrat Certain platforms (like Linux, IIRC) don't actually "commit" to an allocation until you really need the memory (i.e. when you access it for the first time). I have no idea why anyone would ever consider that to be a good idea. Also, you need enough *contiguous* memory for each allocation.

Comment: Well then the issue is that I have not enough contingious memory and indeed use linux. Maybe vote for close if question is not for Stackoverflow